# 'rm' not found in PATH or not executable

Tags: linux, debian

Okay, I made a **big** mistake. I attempted to upgrade from coreutils:i386 to coreutils:arm64, and that went wrong. Now I don't have a lot of programs any more, including rm, touch, chmod and mv.

So, I attempt to run `apt-get install coreutils`:

```
root@srv028:/tmp# apt-get install coreutils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  coreutils
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,727 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
dpkg: warning: 'rm' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I do have a backup, but that would mean half a day of work is lost. So my question is, is this recoverable?
And if so, how?

Comment: Why can't you backup your work then restore your working backup?

Comment: I could, but I made that backup about 6 hours ago and have been working on it since. Therefore I'm also only looking at a cost-effective method, if it'd take another six hours to get back up and running it's not worth it.

Comment: You could try to download coreutils manually and extract the files you need to some non-standard location included in PATH (probably /usr/local/bin). Then use the so-installed rm etc. to re-install coreutils.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, at first thanks to the apport of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115743/i-deleted-bin-rm-how-do-i-recover-it

> ```
> sudo touch /bin/rm
> sudo chmod +x /bin/rm
> apt-get download coreutils
> sudo dpkg --unpack coreutils*
> ```

You create a dummy file where the rm should be, an adds execution permission. You download the coreutils application (not sudo needed) and after that you install the files. dpkg will read coreutils package and make the install.

Comment: And what to do if neither touch nor chmod is available? I managed to work around the touch not being there by using nano, but chmod becomes a bit more difficult.

Comment: Not sure, but it could be possible to start with a linux usb bootable to have access as root with a whole packet of commands, and then use the chmod included in that boot to make the modification.

Comment: By now I've just reinstalled the system, but as it was a virtual machine I could not have. Even though this question is no longer relevant I'll keep it here, in case an answer comes by that would probably have worked, as an aid for people who undergo the same mistake.

Comment: (1) This question — [How to chmod without /usr/bin/chmod?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83862/80216) — might be relevant, useful, educational and/or entertaining, but it is about a situation where `/usr/bin/chmod` still existed, but had simply been chmod'ed to a non-executable mode. It also assumes that most of the system is intact. (2) [Unix Recovery Legend](https://www.ee.ryerson.ca/~elf/hack/recovery.html) tells the story of the recovery from a much worse disaster, and is also educational and entertaining. (3) Why do you say that you could not have booted a VM from external media?

Answer (score 1):

I had busybox still available. So i extracted the deb file using `dpkg -x coreutils_8.23-4_amd64.deb coreutils` and then copied the file using `busybox cp coreutils/bin/* /bin/` and `busybox chmod +x /bin/*`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I made the same mistake.  For me, neither touch nor chmod worked... But: Lucky me, I had emacs installed.  So:

1. `sudo emacs`
2. Create an empty file /bin/rm
3. In emacs, do `C-x set-file-modes` and change the mode of /bin/rm to +x.
4. `apt-get download coreutils`
5. `sudo dpkg --unpack coreutils*`